# Linq to XML join and add data?

Tags: c#, xml, join, linq-to-xml

Given XML like this:

```
<Root>
    <Element>
        <Id>1</Id>
    </Element>
    <Element>
        <Id>2</Id>
    </Element>
    <Element>
        <Id>3</Id>
    </Element>
</Root>
```

And an IEnumerable with this data:

```
[0] = { Id = 1, Data = 429 }
[1] = { Id = 2, Data = 271 }
[2] = { Id = 3, Data = 328 }
```

Is there an elegant way using LINQ to XML to join the IEnumerable data with the XML based on the common `Id` without individually querying for each element to link the data with?

So the result would look like this:

```
<Root>
    <Element>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Data>429</Data>
    </Element>
    <Element>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <Data>271</Data>
    </Element>
    <Element>
        <Id>3</Id>
        <Data>328</Data>
    </Element>
</Root>
```

The only thing I can come up with is something like this, but I was hoping there was a cleaner method:

```
foreach(var d in MyIEnumerable)
{
    XElement element = (from x in MyXDoc.Elements("Element")
                        where x.Element("Id").Value == d.Id
                        select x).Single();

    element.Add(new XElement("Data", d.Data));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use a `Tuple<Element, XElement>`. (The `Element` is the class that has ID and Data in it.)

```
var output = from el in els
             join xmlEl in xdoc.Root.Elements("Element") on el.Id equals int.Parse(xmlEl.Element("Id").Value)
             select new Tuple<Element, XElement>(el, xmlEl);

foreach(var item in output)
{
    item.Item2.Add(new XElement("Data", item.Item1.Data));
}
```

If you don't have tuples then you can create an anonymous class instead.

```
select new {ObjEl = el, XmlEl = xmlEl}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do something like:

```
var elements = MyXDoc.Elements("Element");
elements.Apply(e => e.Add(new XElement("Data", MyIEnumerable.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == e.Element("Id").Value).Data)));
```

Where the `Apply` extension method is defined as:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Apply<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (var item in enumerable)
        {
            action(item);
        }
    }
}
```